# Javascript function executes asynchronously, without me wanting it to

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, synchronization

I am making a navigation webapplication for a school project. It uses a program called "EasyStar" for the pathfinding. Because I need to calculate distances between some points pretty often, I decided to make a function for it:

```
function Distance(A, B, C, D, G) {
easystar.setGrid(G);
easystar.findPath(A, B, C, D, function( path ) {
Dist = 1;
for (F = 0; F < Dist; F++){
if (typeof path[F] !== "undefined"){Dist++;}
else{}
}});
easystar.calculate();
}
```

The problem I'm facing is that when I call the function, it finished after the next bit of code is executed: If I log Dist in the console both at the end of the function itself and right after the function is supposed to execute, it ends up with:

```
undefined
[The actual distance]
```

If I do something like this

```
setTimeout(function(){console.log(Dist)},0.001)
```

or a 0.001 ms delay it does display it correctly, and I can start working with the value of Dist. The problem with that solution is that I can't keep that up for the entire document, as it would get really messy and I'm not even sure if it would work as a permanent solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since EasyPath runs asynchronously, you can't be sure when the function you pass to `findPath()` will be executed. For this reason, any logic that needs the final value of `Dist` will have to be placed in this function. As this can get ugly very quickly, you can pass in a success callback to `Distance()` that gets called after `Dist` is calculated, like so.

```
function myFunc() {
    var grid = [
        [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    ];
    Distance(0, 0, 4, 0, grid, handleDist);
};

var handleDist = function(dist) {
    // Do something with dist.
};

function Distance(A, B, C, D, G, callback) {
    easystar.setGrid(G);
    easystar.findPath(A, B, C, D, function(path) {
        Dist = 1;
        for (F = 0; F < Dist; F++) {
            if (typeof path[F] !== null) { Dist++; }
            else { }
        }
        callback(Dist);
    });
    easystar.calculate();
}
```

`myFunc()` is just an example of how `Distance()` might be called. As you can see `handleDist()` is a separate function you will write to handle the final value of `Dist`. You pass this in to `Distance()` and call it in the callback of `findPath()`.

[Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) would help further clean up this code, but as I'm unfamiliar with EasyPath, I'm not sure it supports them.

Comment: As a fairly new programmer it took me a while to realise what the callback was doing exactly, but I think I get it! you write a seperate funtion to substitute, or "inject", into the funtion `Distance()` so it can run inside there. This is a great idea, and I'm pretty sure I can go on now!

Comment: That's exactly the idea. This is how asynchronous event-based actions are commonly handled in Javascript. You will become more familiar with this pattern as you get more experience with the language.

Comment: Also, since you are new here, don't forget to accept an answer if your question is resolved.